# How to have multiple JavaScript functions with variables in the same file?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am curious as to the proper method to have multiple functions with variables in one JavaScript file.  I cannot seem to understand the proper syntax for it.

I am trying to replicate the example from randomsnippets.com but would like other areas of the form to have an option to add more.  I do not want to have a bunch of script tags or js files for that matter!

So to recap, I would like something like this

```
variable a = value
variable b = value
function name(something){
stuff for variable a
}
function name(something){
stuff for variable b
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

```html
<script>
      var counter = 1;

    var limit = 3;

    function addInput(divName){

         if (counter == limit)  {

              alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");

         }

         else {

              var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

              newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";

              document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

              counter++;

         }

    }
  </script>
<form method="POST">

     <div id="dynamicInput">

          Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">

     </div>

     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

</form>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Just make sure to use different names and you should be fine with multiple functions.

Comment: As a general rule, try to avoid globals. You can keep references to *counter* and *limit* using closures instead.

Comment: To say what is the problem, are you insinuating that my requested result is in fact correct? I tried to replicate it with the full scrip as I found from the website and it broke the functions.  Maybe according to the others, I messed up in naming of items.  Will try again.

Comment: What I got from your post is.Limit is a constant. Count is the only global variable. I can suggest you to remove count variable from global and you can get number of child from parent element easily. $( "#"+divName ).children( "input" ).length;

Comment: @Born2Discover Yes, the example snippet you posted appears to work. (Doesn't it for you?) If you tried something different and it broke, please post *that* full broken script.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It was a combination of all input.  It was correct format, however there were elements that I had crossed IDs with and therefore it was the result of not maintaining ID integrity which caused me to believe I was not doing things correctly.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know I got the your problem correctly. I am assuming the problem with global variable and trying to give a solution. If I were you.I will get this kind of approach. Using a global variable is not a good solution. When the page is getting refresh variables will be reset. Then accuracy will not be there. What I suggest is get the input count on the fly.

```
var limit = 3;

function addInput(divName){

    var counter = 1;
    counter=$( "#"+divName ).children( "input" ).length;

if (counter == limit)  {

    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");

}

else {

    var newdiv = document.getElementById(divName );

    newdiv.innerHTML = newdiv.innerHTML+"<br/>Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";

    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

    counter++;

}

}
```